# Giving a Screensaver Administrative Privileges

Tags: windows-7, uac, administrator, screensaver

I have a custom screensaver that does some file I/O. I am on a Windows 7 desktop.

Unfortunately, I get errors that access to path is denied.

On an **exe** file I can go to *Properties > Compatibility* and check '*Run this program as an administrator*'. However, there is no such option for **scr** files.

What else can I do to give this **scr** administrative privileges?

Comment: Allow a screen saver to access private information sounds like an information disclosure security vulnerability. (Remember that a screen saver runs when the logged-in user is not present. If it showed information about the logged-in user, then it would be revealing private information to the untrusted person standing in front of the computer.)

Comment: Understood. But if the screensaver comes from a trusted source, or is coded by the user themselves, and they know what it does, and they have administrative privileges themselves, shouldn't they be able to grant necessary permissions? Or will the Windows not allow it?

Comment: Like any other program, the screen saver cannot elevate privileges beyond those of the user who is running the screen saver.

Comment: Right, so if I can access those files, I should be able to allow the screensaver to do the same? So how can I do this?

Comment: Is the screen saver running on your account?

Comment: Yes, the screen saver is running on my account, which is an administrator account.

Comment: is this a special path? one where you would normally get an uac prompt if you modify like something in program files, etc?

Comment: Yes, the files that the screen saver is trying to read are under the _Program Files_ directory, which is where I put my screen saver.